# Trying to find groups of letters with regex

Tags: php, regex, search, find

I need to find 1 or more defined groups of characters enclosed in parentheses. If more than one group is present it will be separated with a hyphen.

Example:

```
(us)
(jp)
(jp-us)
(jp-us-eu)
```

I've figured out how to find the group if the string only contains one group:

```
/\(us\)|\(jp\)/
```

However, I am baffled when it comes to finding more than one, separated by a hypen and in no particular order: `(us-jp)` OR `(jp-us)`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for?  The regex you provide will locate both (us-jp) and (jp-us).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\((\b(?:en|jp|us|eu)-?\b)+\)
```

Explanation:

```
\(                     // opening paren
(                      // match group one
  \b                   // word boundary
  (?:en|jp|us|eu)      // your defined strings
  -?                   // a hyphen, optional
  \b                   // another word boundary
)+                     // repeat
\)                     // closing paren
```

matches:

```
(us)
(jp) 
(jp-us)
(jp-us-eu)
```

does not match:

```
(jp-us-eu-)
(-jp-us-eu)
(-jp-us-eu-)
```

Comment: Good solution, I had a longer one, but specifying the `\b` word boundary before the parentheses ensures that we don't have a trailing dash there.

Comment: Could you explain what the `?:` is doing in this context?

Comment: @user See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do

Comment: @Tomalak Nice!  These things are notoriously hard to search on Google.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/\([a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})*\)/
```

That will match any two letter sequence in parenthesis that my contain more two letter sequences separeted by hypens. So `(ab)`, `(ab-cd)`, `(ab-cd-ef)`, `(ab-cd-ef-gh)` etc.

Comment: Another possibility, +1. Does not match the "defined groups of characters" requirement, though. However, fixing this would require repeating yourself.