# What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, capturing-group, regex-group

How are non-capturing groups, i.e., `(?:)`, used in regular expressions and what are they good for?

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Groups".

Answer (score 3010, accepted):

Let me try to explain this with an example.

Consider the following text:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex
```

Now, if I apply the regex below over it (I did not escape the slashes for clarity; when using it, slashes would have to be escaped to `\/` )...

```
(https?|ftp)://([^/\r\n]+)(/[^\r\n]*)?      // slashes not escaped for clarity
(https?|ftp):\/\/([^/\r\n]+)(\/[^\r\n]*)?   // slashes escaped
```

... I would get the following result:

```
Match "http://stackoverflow.com/"
     Group 1: "http"
     Group 2: "stackoverflow.com"
     Group 3: "/"

Match "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex"
     Group 1: "https"
     Group 2: "stackoverflow.com"
     Group 3: "/questions/tagged/regex"
```

But I don't care about the protocol -- I just want the host and path of the URL. So, I change the regex to include the non-capturing group `(?:)`.

```
(?:https?|ftp):\/\/([^/\r\n]+)(\/[^\r\n]*)?   // slashes escaped
```

Now, my result looks like this:

```
Match "http://stackoverflow.com/"
     Group 1: "stackoverflow.com"
     Group 2: "/"

Match "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex"
     Group 1: "stackoverflow.com"
     Group 2: "/questions/tagged/regex"
```

See? The first group has not been captured. The parser uses it to match the text, but ignores it later, in the final result.

---

### EDIT:

As requested, let me try to explain groups too.

Well, groups serve many purposes. They can help you to extract exact information from a bigger match (which can also be named), they let you rematch a previous matched group, and can be used for substitutions. Let's try some examples, shall we?

Imagine you have some kind of XML or HTML (be aware that [regex may not be the best tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but it is nice as an example). You want to parse the tags, so you could do something like this (I have added spaces to make it easier to understand):

```
   \<(?<TAG>.+?)\> [^<]*? \</\k<TAG>\>
or
   \<(.+?)\> [^<]*? \</\1\>
```

The first regex has a named group (TAG), while the second one uses a common group. Both regexes do the same thing: they use the value from the first group (the name of the tag) to match the closing tag. The difference is that the first one uses the name to match the value, and the second one uses the group index (which starts at 1).

Let's try some substitutions now. Consider the following text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer feugiat fames malesuada pretium egestas.
```

Now, let's use this dumb regex over it:

```regex
\b(\S)(\S)(\S)(\S*)\b
```

This regex matches words with at least 3 characters, and uses groups to separate the first three letters. The result is this:

```
Match "Lorem"
     Group 1: "L"
     Group 2: "o"
     Group 3: "r"
     Group 4: "em"
Match "ipsum"
     Group 1: "i"
     Group 2: "p"
     Group 3: "s"
     Group 4: "um"
...

Match "consectetuer"
     Group 1: "c"
     Group 2: "o"
     Group 3: "n"
     Group 4: "sectetuer"
...
```

So, if we apply the substitution string:

```
$1_$3$2_$4
```

... over it, we are trying to use the first group, add an underscore, use the third group, then the second group, add another underscore, and then the fourth group. The resulting string would be like the one below.

```
L_ro_em i_sp_um d_lo_or s_ti_ a_em_t c_no_sectetuer f_ue_giat f_ma_es m_la_esuada p_er_tium e_eg_stas.
```

You can use named groups for substitutions too, using `${name}`.

To play around with regexes, I recommend http://regex101.com/, which offers a good amount of details on how the regex works; it also offers a few regex engines to choose from.

Comment: @ajsie: Traditional (capturing) groups are most useful if you're performing a replacement operation on the results.  Here's an example where I'm grabbing comma-separated last & first names and then reversing their order (thanks to named groups)... http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=16892996-64d4-4f10-860a-24f28dad7e30

Comment: can i use it like this? 
([?:]http|ftp)://([^/\r\n]+)(/[^\r\n]*)?
Is it same as (?:http|ftp)://([^/\r\n]+)(/[^\r\n]*)? . please reply soon

Comment: Might also point out that non-capturing groups are uniquely useful when using regex as split delimiters: "Alice and Bob"-split"\s+(?:and|or)\s+"

Comment: It would be interesting to have the difference between non-capturing groups (?:), and lookahead and lookbehind assertions (?=, ?!) explained. I just started learning about regular expressions, but from what I understand, non-capturing groups are used for matching and "return" what they match, but that "return value" is not "stored" for back-referencing. Lookahead and lookbehind assertions on the other hand are not only not "stored", they are also not part of a match, they just assert that something would match, but their "match" value is ignored, if I'm not mistaken... (Am I roughly right?)

Comment: ok, got what the ?: does.  Can someone explain what the ([^/\r\n]+) does?  To me that's looking for a / then 1 or more line break at the beginning of the string but I fail to see how that helps match a url.

Comment: [] is a set; 
[123] matches any char inside the set once; 
[^123] matches anything NOT inside the set once;
[^/\r\n]+ matches one or more chars that are different from /, \r, \n.

Comment: that regex needs to be escaped. (?:https?|ftp):\/\/([^\/\r\n]+)(\/[^\r\n]*)?

Comment: what is the [^/\r\n]  doing? should that forward slash be a backslash to escape the \r ??

Comment: What is also important there is that regex with non-capturing groups `(?:` is much faster than the same regex with capturing groups '('. So we should use non-capturing groups when we don't need capturing groups.

Comment: You recommend https://regex101.com/, but when I paste there 
your first regex `(?:https?|ftp)://([^/\r\n]+)(/[^\r\n]*)?` I get "pattern error" "An unescaped delimiter must be escaped; in most languages with a backslash". Are you using a particular engine in which this is normal syntax?

Comment: @Santopedro You just need to escape the slashes, most likely. It depends on the engine. I'll modify it to make it clear.

Answer (score 248):

You can use capturing groups to organize and parse an expression.  A non-capturing group has the first benefit, but doesn't have the overhead of the second.  You can still say a non-capturing group is optional, for example.

Say you want to match numeric text, but some numbers could be written as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th,...  If you want to capture the numeric part, but not the (optional) suffix you can use a non-capturing group.

```
([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?
```

That will match numbers in the form 1, 2, 3... or in the form 1st, 2nd, 3rd,... but it will only capture the numeric part.

Comment: Without non-capturing group, I could do: `([0-9]+)(st|nd|rd|th)?`? With `\1` I have the number, no `?:` needed. BTW what is the `?` at the end?

Comment: In this case, `?` at the end means the capture group is optional.

Comment: I agree with @Timo, I don't see why non-capture group is a thing in this example

Answer (score 160):

`?:` is used when you want to group an expression, but you do not want to save it as a matched/captured portion of the string.

An example would be something to match an IP address:

```
/(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/
```

Note that I don't care about saving the first 3 octets, but the `(?:...)` grouping allows me to shorten the regex without incurring the overhead of capturing and storing a match.

Comment: For inexperienced readers: This would match an IP address, but also invalid IP addresses. An expression to *validate* an IP address would be much more complex. So, don't use this to validate an IP address.

Comment: Just to add, this is saying you have 1 to 3 digits followed by a ".", exactly three times, followed by another 1 to 3 digits.

Comment: What is the difference of non-capturing groups in PCRE (Perl) and ERE (extended regular expressions)?

Comment: To know the difference, I recommend to check it here [regex-tester](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/54df482cf536), with different engines.

Answer (score 71):

HISTORICAL MOTIVATION:

The existence of non-capturing groups can be explained with the use of parenthesis.

Consider the expressions `(a|b)c` and `a|bc`, due to priority of concatenation over `|`, these expressions represent two different languages (`{ac, bc}` and `{a, bc}` respectively).

However, the parenthesis are also used as a matching group (as explained by the other answers...).

When you want to have parenthesis but not capture the sub-expression you use NON-CAPTURING GROUPS. In the example, `(?:a|b)c`

Comment: only answer alluded why even we need grouping. +1

Answer (score 55):

**Let me try this with an example:**

Regex Code: `(?:animal)(?:=)(\w+)(,)\1\2`

**Search String:**

Line 1 - `animal=cat,dog,cat,tiger,dog`

Line 2 - `animal=cat,cat,dog,dog,tiger`

Line 3 - `animal=dog,dog,cat,cat,tiger`

`(?:animal)` --> Non-Captured Group 1

`(?:=)`--> Non-Captured Group 2

`(\w+)`--> Captured Group 1

`(,)`--> Captured Group 2

`\1` --> result of captured group 1 i.e In Line 1 is cat, In Line 2 is cat, In Line 3 is dog.

`\2` --> result of captured group 2 i.e comma (,)

So in this code by giving `\1` and `\2` we recall or repeat the result of captured group 1 and 2 respectively later in the code.

As per the order of code `(?:animal)` should be group 1 and `(?:=)` should be group 2 and continues..

but by giving the `?:` we make the match-group non captured (which do not count off in matched group, so the grouping number starts from the first captured group and not the non captured), so that the repetition of the result of match-group `(?:animal)` can't be called later in code.

**Hope this explains the use of non capturing group.**

[image]

Comment: `(?:animal=)(\w+)(,)\1\2` Since the only match for `(?:animal)(?:=)` is `animal=`, there is no reason to have two non-capturing groups.  On the other hand, if you want to capture the first word, `(animal)(?:=)(\w+)(,)\2\3` would do the same matching of repeating the first animal and comma.  E.g. if your text also includes vegetables and minerals, you could use `(?:\w+)(?:=)(\w+)(,)\2\3` and then you have the category or whatever you want to call the word before the equals, in group 1.  The non-capturing group in this case would be only the `(?:=)` and this would be thrown away.

Answer (score 47):

It makes the group non-capturing, which means that the substring matched by that group will not be included in the list of captures. An example in ruby to illustrate the difference:

```
"abc".match(/(.)(.)./).captures #=> ["a","b"]
"abc".match(/(?:.)(.)./).captures #=> ["b"]
```

Comment: Why can't we just use "abc".match(/.(.)./).captures here ?

Comment: @PRASANNASARAF You can, of course. The point of the code was to show that `(?:)` does not produce a capture, not to demonstrate a useful example of `(?:)`. `(?:)` is useful when you want to group a sub-expression (say when you want to apply quantifiers to a non-atomic sub-expression or if you want to restrict the scope of a `|`), but you don't want to capture anything.

Answer (score 24):

Groups that **capture** you can use later on in the regex to match **OR** you can use them in the replacement part of the regex.  Making a **non-capturing** group simply exempts that group from being used for either of these reasons.

Non-capturing groups are great if you are trying to capture many different things and there are some groups you don't want to capture.

Thats pretty much the reason they exist.  While you are learning about groups, learn about [Atomic Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), they do a lot!  There is also lookaround groups but they are a little more complex and not used so much.

Example of using later on in the regex (backreference):

`<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*?</\1>`  [ Finds an xml tag (without ns support) ]

`([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)` is a capturing group (in this case it is the tagname)

Later on in the regex is `\1` which means it will only match the same text that was in the first group (the `([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)` group) (in this case it is matching the end tag).

Comment: could you give a simple example of how it will be used later to match OR?

Comment: i mean you can use to to match later or you can use it in the replacement.  The or in that sentence was just to show you there are two uses for a capturing group

Answer (score 22):

A Simple Answer

Use them to ensure one of several possibilities occur here `(?:one|two)` or an optional phrase `camp(?:site)?` or in general, anywhere you want to establish a group/phrase/section without needing to refer to it specifically.

They keep your captured group(s) count to a minimum.

Answer (score 19):

**tl;dr** non-capturing groups, as the name suggests are the parts of the regex that you do not want to be included in the capture and `?:` is a way to define a group as being non-capturing.

Let's say you have an email address `example@example.com`. The following regex will create two **groups**, the id part and @example.com part. `(\p{Alpha}*[a-z])(@example.com)`. For simplicity's sake, we are extracting the whole domain name including the `@` character.

Now let's say, you only need the id part of the address. What you want to do is to grab the first group of the match result, surrounded by `()` in the regex and the way to do this is to use the non-capturing group syntax, i.e. `?:`. So the regex `(\p{Alpha}*[a-z])(?:@example.com)` will return just the id part of the email.

Comment: I was struggling to understand all those answers here until I scrolled down to yours!

Comment: Non-capturing groups are included in the match.  But they're not captured.  This means that when you list the captured groups, the non-captured group(s) are not in that list.  They are also not available for referencing later in the expression.  I.e. if you did not care about the domain, you could use `(\w+)@\w.\w.*` and you'd only capture the ID portion.  But if it has to be example.com, and you want to throw away the example.com because all the good matches have it, you'd use the non-capturing group.  `(\w+)@(?:example.com)`.

Comment: @Jeter-work 's comment here is concise and readable enough in of itself that it ought to be an answer to the question!

Comment: Not sure I understand the point here. If you know the domain is always "@example.com" and want to keep ID portion, this regex `(\w+)@example.com` would also work. You would have the ID captured on the first group.

Answer (score 16):

I cannot comment on the top answers to say this: I would like to add an explicit point which is only implied in the top answers:

The non-capturing group `(?:...)` does **not remove** any characters from the original full match, **it only** reorganises the regex visually to the programmer.

To access a specific part of the regex without defined extraneous characters you would always need to use `.group(<index>)`

Comment: You have provided the most important hint that was missing in the rest of the answers. I tried all the examples in them and using the choicest of expletives, as I did not get the desired result. Only your posting showed me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 12):

To complement other good answers in this thread, I want to add an interesting observation that I came across.

**Finding**: You can have a capturing group *inside* a non-capturing group.

**Problem Details**: Have a look at below regex for matching web urls:

```
var parse_url_regex = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
```

Here is my input url string:

```
var url = "http://www.ora.com:80/goodparts?q#fragment";
```

The first group in my regex `(?:([A-Za-z]+):)` is a non-capturing group which matches the protocol scheme (`http`) and colon (`:`) character. In continuation it becomes `http:`. But when I ran below code:

```
console.debug(parse_url_regex.exec(url));
```

I could see that the 1<sup>st</sup> index of the returned array was containing the string `http` instead (Refer screenshot).

[image]

At this point, my thinking was that `http` and colon `:` both will not get reported in the output as they are inside a non-capturing group. If the first regex group `(?:([A-Za-z]+):)` is a non-capturing group then why it is returning `http` string in the output array?

**Explanation**: So if you notice, `([A-Za-z]+)` is a capturing group (not having `?:` at the beginning). But this capturing group is itself inside a non-capturing group `(?:([A-Za-z]+):)` followed by a `:` character. That's why the text `http` still gets captured but the colon `:` character which is falling inside the non-capturing group (but outside the capturing group ) doesn't get reported in the output array.

Answer (score 11):

Well I am a JavaScript developer and will try to explain its significance pertaining to JavaScript.

Consider a scenario where you want to match `cat is animal`
when you would like match cat and animal and both should have a `is` in between them.

```
 // this will ignore "is" as that's is what we want
"cat is animal".match(/(cat)(?: is )(animal)/) ;
result ["cat is animal", "cat", "animal"]

 // using lookahead pattern it will match only "cat" we can
 // use lookahead but the problem is we can not give anything
 // at the back of lookahead pattern
"cat is animal".match(/cat(?= is animal)/) ;
result ["cat"]

 //so I gave another grouping parenthesis for animal
 // in lookahead pattern to match animal as well
"cat is animal".match(/(cat)(?= is (animal))/) ;
result ["cat", "cat", "animal"]

 // we got extra cat in above example so removing another grouping
"cat is animal".match(/cat(?= is (animal))/) ;
result ["cat", "animal"]
```

Answer (score 9):

In complex regular expressions you may have the situation arise where you wish to use a large number of groups some of which are there for repetition matching and some of which are there to provide back references. By default the text matching each group is loaded into the backreference array. Where we have lots of groups and only need to be able to reference some of them from the backreference array we can override this default behaviour to tell the regular expression that certain groups are there only for repetition handling and do not need to be captured and stored in the backreference array.

Answer (score 7):

Let me take to you an example of geo coordinate, the below matches two groups

```
Latitude,Longitude

([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Lets take one `([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

co-ordinate can be whole number like `58` or could be `58.666` 
Hence the optional (`.666`) second part `(\.\d+)?` is mentioned.

```
(...)? - for optional
```

But it is parenthesised, that will be another group of match. and we dont want two matches one for `58` and another for `.666`, we need single latitude as match. Here comes non-capturing group `(?:)`

with non-capturing group `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, 58.666 and 58 both are single match

Answer (score 6):

(?: ... ) acts as a group ( ... ) but doesn't capture the matched data. It's really much more efficient than a standard capture group. It is use when you want to group something but don't need to reuse it later. @Toto

Answer (score 5):

Its extremely simple, We can understand with simple date example, suppose if the date is mentioned as 1st January 2019 or 2nd May 2019 or any other date and we simply want to convert it to **dd/mm/yyyy** format we would not need the month's name which is January or February for that matter, so in order to capture the numeric part, but not the (optional) suffix you can use a non-capturing group.

so the regular expression would be,

```
([0-9]+)(?:January|February)?
```

Its as simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

I think I would give you the answer. Don't use capture variables without checking that the match succeeded.

The capture variables, `$1`, etc, are not valid unless the match succeeded, and they're not cleared, either.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use warnings;
use strict;   
$_ = "bronto saurus burger";
if (/(?:bronto)? saurus (steak|burger)/)
{
    print "Fred wants a  $1";
}
else
{
    print "Fred dont wants a $1 $2";
}
```

In the above example, to avoid capturing bronto in `$1`, `(?:)` is used.

If the pattern is matched , then `$1` is captured as next grouped pattern.

**So, the output will be as below:**

```
Fred wants a burger
```

It is Useful if you don't want the matches to be saved.

Answer (score 3):

Open your Google Chrome devTools and then Console tab: and type this:

```
"Peace".match(/(\w)(\w)(\w)/)
```

Run it and you will see:

```
["Pea", "P", "e", "a", index: 0, input: "Peace", groups: undefined]
```

The `JavaScript` RegExp engine capture three groups, the items with indexes 1,2,3. Now  use non-capturing mark to see the result.

```
"Peace".match(/(?:\w)(\w)(\w)/)
```

The result is:

```
["Pea", "e", "a", index: 0, input: "Peace", groups: undefined]
```

This is obvious what is non capturing group.